# Varying Length of Rows in Python

Tags: python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to write a code for a text file that will have varying lengths of rows each time it is run. In the raw data, a certain number of rows must be skipped to get to the data that will eventually be graphed. Here is the code I have now to read in the text file (with 'G' representing an arbitrary data file we will load:

```
t,x,y = np.loadtxt(G, delimiter = ',', skiprows = 15, usecols = (0,1,2),unpack = True)
```

How can I write it so that the "skiprows" value can vary based on the new row number? Here is an excerpt of the raw data file:

```
30.000,   0.0009,    0.015                        
25.000,   0.0008,    0.013     
20.000,   0.0012,    0.074   

Time,     CMOD,     Load     

0.000,  -0.0046,    0.104
```

The data I want to analyze is the second set of values under the headings "Time, CMOD, Load". Thus, the group of data above will have a varying row number from test to test.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not write to different files? Wouldn't that be easier? Then you wouldn't have to store the number of lines to skip.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't write to different files as this is how someone else wants the format to be :(

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `loadtxt` will do what you want on its own, but you could work through the lines of your file first to find the header, and then hand over to it:

```
import numpy as np
with open('so.txt') as fi:
    while True:
        line = fi.readline()
        if not line:
            # header line not encountered - handle it here somehow
            import sys; sys.exit()
        if line.strip() == 'Time, CMOD, Load':
            break
    t,x,y = np.loadtxt(fi, delimiter = ',', skiprows = 1,
                       usecols = (0,1,2),unpack = True)

print(t,x,y)
```

Note that the `skiprows=1` here skips the blank line *after* the header you're looking for.

Comment: `np.loadtxt` can accept an iterator as its first argument. So you can save memory by replacing `fi.readlines()` with `fi`.

Comment: For some reason I'm getting "IndexError: list index out of range".

Comment: @Chelsea: It's always helpful to include the line of code that generates the error. Even better, to edit the question to include the full traceback error message.

Comment: I forgot to mention the column headings "Time, CMOD, Load" appear above the first set of data as well. So I need a way to find when these column headings appear for the second time.

Comment: @Chelsea: if the first header is the first line of the file, just `fi.readline()` before the `while` loop to skip it. You'll need to produce more code and the traceback to track down the `IndexError`.

Comment: Here's the full error (sorry, I just started learning Python two days ago so I really only know the basics):  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    DCT('test.txt')
  File "C:\Python27\DCT test.py", line 43, in DCT
    t,x,y = np.loadtxt(G, delimiter = ',', skiprows=2, usecols = (0,1,2),unpack = True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 846, in loadtxt
    vals = [vals[i] for i in usecols]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Do you have other content below the data you're reading in with `loadtxt`? For example, a footer or blank line?